# Shift key is not working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my ThinkPad E450 and both my shift keys are not responding. Please help.

Update-

```
vishal@pop-os:~$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `setxkbmap -query`.

Comment: You can try changing your keyboard layout. Try something like US AltGr International.